Is it possible to adapt Pohlig Hellman to finite/Galois fields having dimension >2 ? If yes how?
In the case of the ecdlp, one can solve each individual discrete logarithm by dividing each point by a prime factor.
But while Pohlig‐Hellman definitely works in $GF(p)$, is it possible to perform a similar adaptation in $GF(p^n)$ with $n>2$ & $p>n$ ?
Or does the polynomial structure of it’s field elements prevents reducing the would be factorized order to smaller individual discrete logarithms ?
If not, what operation should be done to apply the individual prime factors to the finite fields polynomial’s elements representing the discrete logarithm to be solved ?
For example, let’s say I want to solve $2×z^8 + z^7 + 6×z^6 + 4×z^5 + 4×z^4 + 3×z^3 + z^2 + 6×z + 1$
$4×z^8 + z^7 + 5×z^5 + 3×z^4 + 4×z^3 + 4×z^2 + 6×z + 2$
in $GF(7^{10})$
How would those 2 elements be written (what does the polynomials would like) in order to solve the subdiscrete log in $2801$ ?

Your example needs clarification. I assume that all instance of 10 should be either deleted or subscripted; you should make clear which element is the target and which is the generator; you need to provided an irreducible degree 10 polynomial of which $z$ is a root.

@DanielS With the point I don t understand the finite field element which is the target doesn t matters. I genereted this example randomly using sagemath just to understand how to do it. What do your mean for example in your last sentence?

@DanielS finite fields elements in my example updated if the sagemath syntax disturb you.

The Pohlig-Hellman attack applies to any cyclic group with composite order. In particular, the multiplicative group of $GF(p^n)$ has order $p^n-1$.
In a multiplicative group, if the factorisation of the group order is $m=q_1^{e_1}\ldots q_r^{e_r}$ then the subgroup of order $q_i$ can be attacked by raising both the generator and the target element to the power $m/q_i$ (powers of $q_i$ can be recovered recurvsively).
In your example, if we represent $GF(7^{10})$ with the default Conway polynomial chosen by sage math (i.e. $z^{10} + z^6 + z^5 + 4z^4 + z^3 + 2z^2 + 3z + 3=0$) and take the element $2^8+^7+6^6+4^5+4^4+3^3+^2+6+1$ as the target for a discrete logarithm problem with respect to the generator $4^8+^7+5^5+3^4+4^3+4^2+6+2$ we can solve in the order 2801 subgroup by raising both elements to the power $(7^{10}-1)/2801$. Thus:
GF7_10.<z>=GF(7^10)
target = 2*^8+^7+6*^6+4*^5+4*^4+3*^3+^2+6*+1
gen = 4*^8+^7+5*^5+3*^4+4*^3+4*^2+6*+2
ph_gen = gen^((7^10-1)/2801)
ph_target = target^((7^10-1)/2801)
print(ph_gen)
print(ph_target)

which outputs 6*z^9 + z^7 + 2*z^6 + z^4 + 2*z^3 + 4*z and 2*z^9 + 3*z^8 + 3*z^7 + 5*z^6 + 4*z^5 + 5*z^4 + 2*z^3 + 4*z^2 + 5*z + 4 respectively.
print(ph_gen.multiplicative_order(),ph_target.multiplicative_order()) confirms that both of these are of order 2801.
We can then call discrete_log(ph_target, ph_gen, 2801, operation='*') to recover the subgroup discrete logarithm: 2675.

I still don’t understand, so I asked an example in my question…

One last thing, there are many pollard rho implementations in computer algebra systems supporting finite fields, but how to ask a speicifc implementation in solving the ffdlp in a given suborder? I m meaning I for example fails to see how do this in magma or pari/gp or sagemath.

Thanks for the edit, but your answer doesn’t works/is wrong. When the whole discrete log is 89293 in my example, the discrete logarithm in order $11$ can be both $0$ or $2$ whereas the finite field elements shouldn’t make it vary.

Ok, I found why : what if the multiplicative order of a given finite field element is at random different from the one of the whole field ? and namely have a prime multiplicative order ?
